# Loading data in mysql and replace empty fields by NULL but not blanks

Tags: mysql, csv, loading

I am loading csv files in MySQL tables using this instruction :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE MYTABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n";
```

Wanting to put null instead of empty fields I wrote this :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE MYTABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
(field1, @field2, field3)
SET
field2 = NULLIF(@field2, '');
```

Works good but as I use NULLIF, even blank fields are put to NULL.

How can I say that just empty fields go to NULL but blanks fields remain the same?

Comment: What is the difference of an "empty" and a "blank" field?

Comment: size of an empty field = 0, size of blanks field = the number of blanks

Comment: One option is: `SET @\`field2\` = IF(CHAR_LENGTH(@\`field2\`) > 0, @\`field2\`, NULL);`